# how to convert text input to java.time.LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf, localdatetime

i'm trying to make form, which will add new Lecture to my University dataBase.
So, model class Lecture has field LocalDateTime date and i need to convert input text from form to LocalDateTime, i getting issue:

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.time.LocalDateTime for property date; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDateTime]
```

my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/createNew")
    public String showSignUpForm(Model model) {
        Lecture lecture = new Lecture();
        model.addAttribute("lecture", lecture);
        return "lecture/SaveLecture";
    }

@PostMapping("/addLecture")
public String createLecture(@Valid Lecture lecture, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "lecture/SaveLecture";
    }

    try {
        lectureService.save(lecture);
    } catch (TimeTableOverlayException e) {
        return "lecture/SaveLecture";
    }

    return this.getAllLectures(model);
}
```

and form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Save new lecture</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/lecture/addLecture}" th:object="${lecture}" method="POST">
    ...
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{date}" id="date" placeholder="Date&Time">
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('date')}" th:errors="*{date}"></span> 
    <br/>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Add lecture">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my Lecture class:

```
public class Lecture {

    private int id;
    private List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    private Teacher teacher;
    private Subject subject;
    private LocalDateTime date;
    private Audience audience;

    public Lecture(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Lecture() {

    }

    public Lecture(Teacher teacher, Subject subject, LocalDateTime date) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Lecture(int id, Teacher teacher, Subject subject, List<Group> groups, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.date = dateTime;
    }

    public Lecture(int id, Teacher teacher, Subject subject, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.date = dateTime;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<Group> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public void setSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDateTime dt) {
        this.date = dt;
    }

    public void setAudience(Audience audience) {
        this.audience = audience;
    }

    public List<Group> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public Subject getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public Audience getAudience() {
        return audience;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((audience == null) ? 0 : audience.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((groups == null) ? 0 : groups.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((subject == null) ? 0 : subject.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((teacher == null) ? 0 : teacher.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Lecture other = (Lecture) obj;
        if (audience == null) {
            if (other.audience != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!audience.equals(other.audience))
            return false;
        if (date == null) {
            if (other.date != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!date.equals(other.date))
            return false;
        if (groups == null) {
            if (other.groups != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!groups.equals(other.groups))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (subject == null) {
            if (other.subject != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!subject.equals(other.subject))
            return false;
        if (teacher == null) {
            if (other.teacher != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!teacher.equals(other.teacher))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

how i can convert it to LocalDateTime? I saw exaples with converting in contollers with annotation @DateTimeFormat, but i dont understand how i can use it in my case...

Comment: add code for `Lecture` class

Comment: @Hemant added it

Comment: Any specific reason you are using an input type of "text" rather than "date"?

Comment: no, i've tried text type and  datetime-local type of input, but problem is same. but i need to save date and time, so date type is not for this case?

Comment: How should the user enter date and time in this field?

Comment: I tried to enter date like "2020-05-18 10:30" , "2020.05.18 10:30:00", "2020.05.18T10:30:00" and in datetime-local but nothing

Comment: try this remove `placeholder="Date&Time"` and set a default date as `lecture.setDate(LocalDateTime.now());` in `@GetMapping("/createNew")`

Comment: @Hemant THANK U. I've do it and i now i see, that the format which it wants is "dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm", with this little ",". i enter date in format like this and it works. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `placeholder="Date&Time"`.
And use a default date :

```java
@GetMapping("/createNew")
    public String showSignUpForm(Model model) {
        Lecture lecture = new Lecture();
        lecture.setDate(LocalDateTime.now())
        model.addAttribute("lecture", lecture);
        return "lecture/SaveLecture";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in comments recommend: try this remove placeholder="Date&Time" and set a default date as lecture.setDate(LocalDateTime.now()); in @GetMapping("/createNew")

I've do it and i now i see, that the format which it wants is "dd.mm.yyyy, hh:mm". i enter date in format like this and it works.

Comment: oh .. even I added answer